# What does "dist" mean in composer when updating?

Tags: laravel, github, composer-php

What does `Now trying to download from dist` mean when we run `composer update`?

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the [documentation](https://getcomposer.org/doc/05-repositories.md#package) :

> Dist: The dist is a packaged version of the package data. Usually a released version, usually a stable release.

Opposed to the source :

> Source: The source is used for development. This will usually originate from a source code repository, such as git. You can fetch this when you want to modify the downloaded package.

Answer (score 3):

It means that it will get the source code by downloading a zip rather than checking it out of a git/mercurial/svn/etc repository.

Dist (distribution package) is much smaller, and thus more handy for deployment while the source checkout is more flexible because since it contains all the development history (commits) for a given package, it lets you to hack the dependency source code and, perhaps, fork it, send a pull request and so on.